# CSS Hover Opacity Transition flicker when hovering over element that is on top of another element

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity

I have an album cover that also has a play button on top of it.

When a user hovers over the album cover, the opacity changes to lighten the image. Likewise, when hovering over the cover, if the user then hovers over the play button, the cover opacity should remain in it's changed state.

The problem is that because I have a transition effect on the opacity, the opacity flickers when hovering back and forth over the cover and the play button.

I created a fiddle to show the issue.

How can I have it so that when initially hovering over the album cover, the opacity transitions, but then hovering over the play button, the opacity simply stays the same without re-transitioning, causing it to flicker?

```css
.play-button-container img:hover,
.play-button:hover + .image {
    opacity: .6;
}

.play-button-container img {
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}

.play-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="play-button-container">
  
    <div class="play-button">
      PLAY
    </div>
    
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://papers.co/wallpaper/papers.co-am19-tycho-art-music-album-cover-illust-simple-white-40-wallpaper.jpg" width="350">
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/659z2ndx/1/

Comment: "cover opacity will remain changed" say what? does it change state or does it remain in current state? Or does one of those indicate a desired behavior?  Please reword to add clarity.

Comment: "the opacity changes to darken the image"  No, it appear to do the opposite to me; what am I missing here?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss On my app, the image will darken, as I have it set up that way. The above is just an example and is not what is implemented in production. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I reworded the question. Should be more clear (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hover over the play button, you change the opacity of the `div` with the class `image`. That is what causes the flicker.

What you should do is change the opacity of the `img`

```css
.play-button-container img:hover,
.play-button:hover + .image > img {
   opacity: .6;
}

.play-button-container img {
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}

.play-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="play-button-container">
  
    <div class="play-button">
      PLAY
    </div>
    
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://papers.co/wallpaper/papers.co-am19-tycho-art-music-album-cover-illust-simple-white-40-wallpaper.jpg" width="350">
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```